# PLSQLerror : SYS_NC

Tags: plsql, database-indexes

I've written a procedure in PL SQL which works with tables and indexes. When I run my procedure for the first time I get this error, but at the  second time everything is ok. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Error at line 2

ORA-00904: "SYS_NC00061 $": invalid identifier

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
PROCEDURE create_archive_tables
  IS
    l_whoami run_signature_t := run_signature_t (g_package, 
'CREATE_ARCHIVE_TABLES');
    
    --define variable
    v_table_name  hot_utils_archive.table_name%TYPE;
    v_db_user VARCHAR2 (70);
    v_index_name VARCHAR2 (400);
    v_table_name_i VARCHAR2 (400);
    v_tablespace VARCHAR2 (400);
    v_columns  VARCHAR2 (1000);
    v_sql_stmt_table_exist VARCHAR2(32767);
    v_sql_stmt  VARCHAR2 ( 32767 );
    v_sql_stmt_index  VARCHAR2 ( 32767 );
    --EXCEPTION
    table_does_not_exist EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_does_not_exist, -00942);
    
    
    
    -- CURSOR for table names
    CURSOR c_archive_table_name IS
        select table_name
        from hot_utils_archive;
        
    -- CURSOR for Indexes
    CURSOR c_index_tables IS
        select a.index_name, a.table_name, a.TABLESPACE_NAME, LISTAGG(b.COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b.COLUMN_NAME) AS columns
        from user_indexes a INNER JOIN user_ind_columns b
        ON a.index_name = b.index_name
        where a.table_name in (select table_name from hot_utils_archive)
        group by a.INDEX_NAME, a.TABLE_NAME, a.TABLESPACE_NAME;
        
BEGIN

    trace.log_proc_start ( l_whoami );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.enable ( NULL );
    SELECT USER INTO v_db_user FROM DUAL;
    
        
    OPEN c_archive_table_name;
    LOOP                                                                                
        FETCH c_archive_table_name
            INTO v_table_name ;
            
        EXIT WHEN c_archive_table_name%NOTFOUND;
        
        BEGIN
                v_sql_stmt_table_exist := 'select * from ' 
                || v_db_user || '_ARCHIVE.' || v_table_name || ' WHERE rownum=1';
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(v_sql_stmt_table_exist);
                
        
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN table_does_not_exist THEN 
                --Create table in Archive DB
                v_sql_stmt :=
                       'CREATE TABLE '
                    || v_db_user || '_ARCHIVE.' || v_table_name
                    || ' AS SELECT * FROM ' || v_table_name
                    ||' WHERE client = ''noname'''
                    ;
                --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_sql_stmt);
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( v_sql_stmt );
                
                --Create indexes
                open c_index_tables;
                LOOP
                    FETCH c_index_tables
                        INTO v_index_name, v_table_name_i, v_tablespace, v_columns;
            
                    EXIT WHEN c_index_tables%NOTFOUND;
                    
                    IF v_table_name = v_table_name_i 
                    THEN
                        v_sql_stmt_index :=
                               'CREATE INDEX ' || v_db_user || '_ARCHIVE.'
                            || v_index_name || ' ON ' || v_db_user || '_ARCHIVE.' || v_table_name
                            || ' (' || v_columns || ') TABLESPACE '
                            || v_db_user || '_ARCHIVE_INDEX'
                            ;
                        --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_sql_stmt_index);
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( v_sql_stmt_index );
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
                CLOSE c_index_tables;
        END;
    END LOOP;        
    CLOSE c_archive_table_name;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    trace.log_proc_fail (l_whoami, error.getText (constants.c_unhandled_exception, trace.get_proc_name (l_whoami), SQLERRM));
                    RAISE;
END create_archive_tables;
```

Comment: Please can you add the PL/SQL you're running into your question? You've asked the equivalent question of "there's a problem with my car. It's a Ford Fiesta. How do I fix it?" - there isn't nearly enough information for us to work out what the problem might be.

Comment: ok, I've done it.